# Why does my for loop only appear to run once?

Tags: javascript

This is one of freecodecamps challenges it passes the for loop inside the filter passes the first element of the array newArg but doesn't for the second one and so on therefore the challenge doesn't pass can someone explain to me why. Please don't write any full solutions as i just want a little help to move forward.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  // Remove all the values
  var newArg = [];
  for (var i=1; i < arguments.length; i++){
         newArg.push(arguments[i]);
       }


 var newArray = arr.filter(function(val){
  for (i = 0; i < newArg.length; i++) {
     return val !== newArg[i];
  } 


 });
 return newArray;



}

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: What happened to the first argument (the array `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]`)?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir the first loop is doing what i want which is pushing all arguments to an  array except the first. The loop i'm having trouble with is the one inside the filter method

Comment: an int does not have property `length` you only get undefined. You should check whether the value is an Array first before running the for loop

Comment: `filter` is already looping through the array why need a second loop?

Comment: A.Lau the loop runs fine using .length i'm not getting undefined im getting only the first element from the array

Comment: To filter the newArg array from the [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `filter` call:

```
var newArray = arr.filter(function(val){
  for (i = 0; i < newArg.length; i++) {
     return val !== newArg[i];
  } 
});
```

is the same as:

```
var newArray = arr.filter(function(val) {
  return val !== newArg[0];
});
```

because you are returning from the very first iteration.

**Solution:**

You'll have to wrap the return statement in an `if` like this:

```
var newArray = arr.filter(function(val){
  for (i = 0; i < newArg.length; i++) {
     if(val === newArg[i]) { // don't return if val !== newArg[i]
       return true;          // return only when they're ===
     }
  }
  return false;              // default return (nothing is found in the array)
});
```

Or use an alternative such as [**`Array.prototype.some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like this:

```
var newArray = arr.filter(function(val){
  return newArg.some(function(arg) { // return true if some item pass the test (false otherwise)
     return arg === val;             // the test
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks! How can i get the result from both iterations returned?

Comment: @Chris check the **solution** section above. The conditions are totally up to you: change them to whatever your need is (filter out, or keep items form `arr`)!

Comment: Thanks alot ibrahim now i just have to figure out how to get the unfiltered values to display instead of the filtered ones. Thanks again!

Comment: @Chris you're welcome! **Hint:** If you want to reverse the result of filter, then swap the `true` and `false` in the first solution (return `false` inside the loop and return `true` at the end), or add a `NOT` (`!`) operator before the `some` call in the second solution like this: `return ! newArg.some(...)`! Or use `Array.prototype.every` which is the opposite of `some`!